# ZIP folder with subfolder in python

Tags: python, zip

I need to zip a folder that containts an .xml file and a .fgdb file by using python. Could anyone help me? I tried a few scripts I found on internet but there is always some technical issue (such as creating an empty zip file, or create zip file I cannot open 'no permission' etc..)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The key to making it work is the [`os.walk()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk) function. Here is a script I assembled in the past that should work. Let me know if you get any exceptions.

```
import zipfile
import os
import sys

def zipfolder(foldername, target_dir):            
    zipobj = zipfile.ZipFile(foldername + '.zip', 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
    rootlen = len(target_dir) + 1
    for base, dirs, files in os.walk(target_dir):
        for file in files:
            fn = os.path.join(base, file)
            zipobj.write(fn, fn[rootlen:])

zipfolder('thenameofthezipfile', 'thedirectorytobezipped') #insert your variables here
sys.exit()
```

Comment: Ok. Help me something first. What is in that case target_dir and what is foldername? Just give me example, please, to be sure. because I tried your code, it runs without exceptions but also without creating zip?!

Comment: Hi Z77, I edited the code to make it more specific to your problem, please check the new script. foldername is the folder name you want to give to the new .zip file and target_dir is the target folder you want to zip. Just put the script in the containing folder of the folder you want to zip, change the variables in the function call and it will work.

Comment: Tnx for you efforts, but still nothing, no created zip file ?!:(

Comment: I have to apologize. Code works. Zip file was created actually in the folder where is .py saved. I didn't pay attention to the fn[rootlen:]. Thank you very much!!!

Comment: FYI I love you. This worked on my first try after about 4 days of trying to find a solution. The trick was to skip ahead one folder so I would not include the top directory.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help :)

Comment: How do I save the new zip file in another destination? and, do I have to use sys.exit()? @JamesMilner

Comment: Took me countless hours trying to get my epubs to work from zipped state. On fedora the native zipping leads to an unreadable epub file. With your method I can finally write my ebooks to zip and convert them to epub. You are my hero.

Comment: If you need to include empty folders, add this block inside de loop:
if not len(dirs) and not len(files):
   fn = os.path.join(base)
   zipobj.write(fn, fn[rootlen:])

Answer (score 3):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10480441/271351) is very helpful, but it took me a moment to fully understand what `rootlen` was for. This example uses some longer variable names to help teach what exactly is going on here. Also included is a block to validate the zip file is correct.

```py
import os
import zipfile

src_path = os.path.join('/', 'some', 'src', 'path')
archive_name = 'myZipFile.zip'
archive_path = os.path.join('/', 'some', 'path', archive_name)

with zipfile.ZipFile(archive_path, 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED) as archive_file:
    for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(src_path):
        for filename in filenames:
            file_path = os.path.join(dirpath, filename)
            archive_file_path = os.path.relpath(file_path, src_path)
            archive_file.write(file_path, archive_file_path)

with zipfile.ZipFile(archive_path, 'r') as archive_file:
    bad_file = zipfile.ZipFile.testzip(archive_file)

    if bad_file:
        raise zipfile.BadZipFile(
            'CRC check failed for {} with file {}'.format(archive_path, bad_file))
```

Answer (score 0):

If someone wants some generic function to utilize in your project

```
def zip_compression_tree(root_path, zip_name):
with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_name, 'w') as z:
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(root):
        for file in files:
            z.write(os.path.join(root, file))
        for directory in dirs:
            z.write(os.path.join(root, directory))
```