# Zipping files in subfolders with size limitation

Tags: python, loops, file, directory, zip

Zipping all files (including those in subfolders) in a folder, a script adapted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10480440/zip-folder-with-subfolder-in-python), is working fine:

```
import zipfile
import os, sys

def zipfolder(filename, target_dir):            
    zipobj = zipfile.ZipFile(filename, 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
    rootlen = len(target_dir)
    for base, dirs, files in os.walk(target_dir):
        for file in files:
            fn = os.path.join(base, file)
            zipobj.write(fn, fn[rootlen:])

zipfolder('C:\\TEMP\\temp.zip', 'C:\\TEMP\\f_with_3_subs\\')
sys.exit()
```

Now I want to limit the files only size smaller than 2 megabytes, I added a line after the for loop, but it doesn't work:

```
for base, dirs, files in os.walk(target_dir):
    for file in files:
        if os.stat(base + file).st_size < 2048 * 1000:
            ......
```

Error message:

```
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

It seems the file names are confused.

What’s the right way to correct it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to stat fn, not base + file (which just concatenates base and file into one string)

```
for base, dirs, files in os.walk(target_dir):
    for file in files:
        fn = os.path.join(base, file)
        if os.stat(fn).st_size < 2048:
```